# Does $(this) query the dom?

Tags: jquery, dom, this

I was wondering if passing this to the jQuery function actually causes it to search in the DOM for it. The question has a specific context.

Let's say I have:

```
$('#foo').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var someVal = $(this).data('someVal');
}
```

Will jQuery query the DOM to provide its functions or are all the information read and taken from the JavaScript object this?

And is there a performance difference to:

```
$('#foo').click(function(){
  var elem = $(this);
  var id = elem.attr('id');
  var someVal = elem.data('someVal');
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't query the DOM in this instance.  `$()` wraps the `this` (or whatever else you have inside it) with a jQuery wrapper object.

By caching it:

```
var $this = $(this);
 // you will see code have a $ before or after a variable ( $this, this$, etc )
 // signifying it is a jQuery wrapped object
```

You have the performance saving of only wrapping it with jQuery once. As opposed to having it go inside jQuery and wrap it over and over again. It is good coding practice to cache it.

**note:** Of course if you have `$('#whatever')` it will be querying the DOM, since you have provided a selector for it to retrieve, then it wraps it with jQuery. So if you'll be reusing it over and over it makes sense to save it as well! `var $whatever = $('#whatever');`

Answer (score 8):

If you have an DOM element in `this`, then `$(this)` does not query the DOM. It just puts a jQuery wrapper object around that one DOM element.

This is not an expensive operation, but you want to avoid doing it *unnecessarily*. for instance, you sometimes see this sort of code:

```
$("some_selector_here").mousemove(function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass('foo')) {
       $(this).doSomething();
   }
   else {
       $(this).doSomethingElse();
   }
});
```

There's just no reason for that. Instead:

```
$("some_selector_here").mousemove(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   if ($this.hasClass('foo')) {
       $this.doSomething();
   }
   else {
       $this.doSomethingElse();
   }
});
```

It almost certainly doesn't matter in, say, a `click` handler, although I would still say it's poor form. But in things that get called a lot, like `mousemove`, well, avoid unnecessary function calls and memory allocation. :-)